# Restriction to Web Console in Apache Drill

Tags: apache-drill

Is there any way to restrict user to stop accessing Web Console or to provide user name & password.
    I am using Drill in embedded mode and in window 8.1 operating System.

> **For Example:-**
>       Drill is running in server, but if someone know my ip address, they can easily access my web console.

So Is there any way to stop accessing my web console. ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a firewall. You can also enable authentication and HTTPS for the Drill web console:

https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-user-authentication/

https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-web-console-and-rest-api-security/#https-support

Comment: :- I have gone through those doc, but didn't able to authenticate my web console. I have make changes in drill-override.conf Files. Following Changes i have
made:-

`http: {
    enabled: true,
    ssl_enabled: true,
    port: 8047
    session_max_idle_secs: 3600
  },`. Now My Question is:-
1) How can i access my web console after enabling SSL?
2) How to Restrict users to access my web console in window?

NOTE:- I am using  Drill in Window with 1.6 version of Apache Drill

Comment: :- How to set username & password for web console in window operating system.??

Comment: :- I have enable ssl in conf file, but still my web ui is accessable through browser. If you type- `https://ip:8074`, then advance button is there in browser, through this one can access web ui. So please tell me some way to restrict the user to view my `WEB UI`